# Notification API and Web Push: Sending messages while page is closed

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

Notification API - http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications
Push API - http://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api

The latter has been released recently, and the former has been available for some years now. What's the PRACTICAL difference between them? On the surface, they look the same, the browser pops up 'Allow notifications' message to which you click allow or block. Then you can send messages whether the focus is on the page or not.

What I haven't been able to figure out, however, is that whether you can send notifications while the page tab is CLOSED. This is the case with the Push API, but is it the case with Notifications API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Push API indeed allows to "wake up" a closed browser.

More specifically, you can use the Push API in combination with the Notification API so that when a push message is received, it notifies the user and when that notification is activated, it opens the browser on the right Web page in the right state.

Comment: Thanks! This is on mobile,right?. On desktop as far as I'm aware you can't send Web Push if the browser is closed (source: canIuse). My main question was: Can you send notifications while the site tab is closed using the Notification API?

Comment: (assuming desktop context):If the tab is closed, the Notification API is not sufficient, you need the Push API to send the notification.

The notification API can only be used from a running tab or from a Service Worker; to get a Service Worker running based on a server-side event, you would want to use the Push API.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my question. Do you have any article regarding combining the Push + the Notification API? From your answer, the part I didn't get was: How is the Notification API relevant here? The Push API alone can be used to notify the user and activate it. So the Notification API must provide something that the Push API doesn't that allows the browser to be in the 'right state' at the right web page.